# Xunit test context to run only once per class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have my test class inheriting from a base, which basically calls a Context method before the Facts, but xunit is calling context once per fact:

```
public class running_some_test : TestContext<ThingImTesting>
public void Because()
[Fact]
public void it_should_do_something()
[Fact]
public void it_should_do_more()
public void Context()
```

I know I could use the IClassFixture , but the TestContext inheritance is providing the test with Because() and Context() methods to override along with the type of SUT. I also think the IClassFixture is too generic, my context is very specific for each test criteria, and SetFixture seems more like a generic set up. Does anyone have a similar pattern that I could follow?

Answer (score 0):

xunit instantiates a new object from your test class per fact. This is done to give each test it's own environment and to make parallelism easier. The recommended way to share context between tests in the same test class is the `IClassFixture<T>` interface.

You can add you `Because()` method to your fixture class if you need access to it in your tests. It looks to me like you're already doing something similar, only you're doing it with inheritance as opposed to composition. You can read up on how the interface works here: https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html#class-fixture

Example from the link:

```
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        Db = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");

        // ... initialize data in the test database ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ... clean up test data from the database ...
    }

    public SqlConnection Db { get; private set; }
}

public class MyDatabaseTests : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    DatabaseFixture fixture;

    public MyDatabaseTests(DatabaseFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    // ... write tests, using fixture.Db to get access to the SQL Server ...
}
```

xunit injects the fixture class via your constructor, so you can do stuff the way you do them now, only you access fixture members via the injected parameter instead of via your super class.

Comment: This implementation suggests that I would need a new Fixture class for every test I write in order to make it specific to that scenario, I'm looking for something a bit less generic

Comment: I'm confused, you don't have to create a new class unless it's needed, and if it's needed, how does your current approach avoid it? What do you mean by less generic?

Comment: Also, the more I think of it, why do you want to move the "set up"-code of each test into a fixture class? It sounds like it'd hurt readability of your tests a lot if every scenario is hidden in another class. You should keep your tests small and focused.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the Mspec set up with 'because - when - then' style tests contained within small focused classes, which IMO definitely improves readability - but it looks like it might need more work with xunit if I don't want the whole class regenerated for each [Fact]